# CakePHP returning missing database table

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I tried all the suggested solution for this problem which is clearing your cache folders. I also disable the cache `Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);` My debug level is set to 2. But I always get a same error. The table that is missing is  only new added table. By the way, I'm only running in my localhost. 
this is my model named Department.php

```
 <?php

class Department extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Department';  
}
?>
```

this is my controller name DepartmentsController.php

```
    <?php
class DepartmentsController extends AppController {

        public $name = 'Departments';
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form','Session');
    public $components = array('RequestHandler','Session');


    function index() {
        $this->Department->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('departments', $this->paginate());
    }    
}
?>
```

Advance thank you for the answer! :D

Comment: What table does cakephp say is missing? Can you include the actual error message in your question? Also, the $name property should probably not be in your Controller, only in your Model, but I don't think this is related to your problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are actually using a database I would try the following things:

1. If your database table isn't named using the cakephp conventions, manually set it:

   public $useTable = 'table_name';
2. Make sure your database config is using the right database in app/config/database.php
3. If that model is in a plugin, use the plugin syntax when including it in the controller:

   public $uses=array('PluginName.Department');